# Maven make same projects with different dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have created one maven project(Desktop application). Now I would like to make the same project, but I want to change some of the dependency versions. 
For example I have lib-1.0.jar and lib-2.0.jar. Now I would like to debug one of my projects with lib-1.0.jar and another project with lib-2.0.jar.
What is the best approach to achieve this? I dont want to edit my pom by hand everytime I debug the project.

Answer (score 4):

Set a [property](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) for the version number, something like:

```
<properties>
    <lib.version>1.0</lib.version>
</properties>
```

And use that in the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>lib.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
    <version>${lib.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can simply override this in a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

```
<profile>
    <id>bleeding-edge</id>
    <properties>
        <lib.version>2.0</lib.version>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And run with the profile to use the different version:

```
mvn -P bleeding-edge clean install
```

Note that this will probably confuse your IDE no end - with some IDE's you can set the profiles used.